# Instalando Kali Linux en dispositivo Android

Tags: linux

Estuve investigando y es posible instalar kalilinux o cualquier distribución de UNIX en los dispositivos Android, usando LINUX DEPLOY.

Dentro de dicho programa hay una opción para descargar la distribución y entre la configuración se selecciona la distribución que quieres bajar y te sale que arquitectura deseas: armel, armlhf, arm64, i386, amd64.

Mi dispositivo es Android 4.4.2 KitKat Modelo TR10CS1, procesador Intel ATOM z2550.

Leyendo conseguí que estos Intel son compatibles con i386, y quisiera saber: ¿Debo bajar ese tipo de IMG de kalilinux o bajar las ARM? pues también leí que los dispositivos Android trabajan con ARM

Comment: Comentario del usuario [Vachb](http://es.stackoverflow.com/users/33842/vachb): Puedes probar desde la página de Kali Linux, en el apartado Descargas.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no se trata sobre programación.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El procesador de tu tablet es intel atom, compatible con arquitectura x86, asi que debes bajar la imagen i386